# Self Joined Table with JSONB Postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have the following **Tables**:

```
Table1
    Table1_id
    Table1_name

Table2 (self join)
    Table2_id
    Table2_name
    Table2_parent_id
    Table1_id

Table3
    Table3_id
    Table3_name
    Table2_id

Table4 
    Table4_id
    Table3_id
    Table5_id

Table5 (self join)
    Table5_id
    Table5_name
    Table5_parent_id

Table6
    Table6_id
    Table5_id
    Table7_id   

Table7
    Table7_id
    Table7_name
```

**Relationships between Tables are:**

```
Table1 has one to many relationship with Table2
Table2 is a self joined table and it has hierarchical data and it has one to many relationship with Table3.
Table3 has many to many relationship with Table5.
Table4 is to handle Many to Many relationship of Table3 & Table5.
Table5 is a self joined table and it has hierarchical data and it has many to many relationship with Table7
Table6 is to handle Many to Many relationship of Table5 & Table7.
```

**What I want to achieve:**

I want to get result like this:

```
    {
    Table1_id,
    Table1_name,
    Table2_data:[
        {
            Table2_id:Table2_id,
            Table2_name:Table2_name,
            Table2_data:[
                {
                    Table2_id:Table2_id,
                    Table2_name: Table2_name,
                    Table2_data:[
                        {
                            Table2_id:Table2_id,
                            Table2_name: Table2_name,
                            Table2_data:[this can also have further children]
                            Table3_data:[this can also have further children]
                        }
                    ],
                    Table3_data:[
                        {
                            Table3_id:Table3_id,
                            Table3_name: Table3_name,
                            Table5_data:[
                                {
                                    Table5_id:Table5_id,
                                    Table5_name: Table5_name,
                                    Table5_data:[
                                        {
                                            Table5_id:Table5_id,
                                            Table5_name: Table5_name,
                                            Table5_data:[this can also have further children]
                                            Table7_data:[this can also have further children]
                                        }
                                    ],
                                    Table7_data:[
                                        {
                                            Table7_id:Table7_id,
                                            Table7_name: Table7_name
                                        }
                                    ],
                                }
                            ],
                        }
                    ],
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

I have tried multiple things including recursive function and multiple jsonb combinations but it is not working. I was able to get data upto some levels but I have to support any nesting levels. Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks